# Spring Security protecting http endpoint and unintended interaction with third party login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to using spring security and am working using it to protect access to an endpoint on my API, I am doing a very simple process where its just an in memory user with a role that allows people with the username and password to query the specific endpoint.

I believe the query process is going to be automated possibly a curl request on a daily schedule or something similar.

The API I have also has a front end client with a separate third party login page. I don't want spring security to interact with any other endpoints in the API so I have done something like

`("api/all-other-urls/**").permitAll()`

the issue is, when I run the front end client and try to login to access the other screens of my client I can't navigate past my login page, in the developer console and in the API terminal it says that I have sent a successful login request, however the username and role is being listed as anonymousUser.
The endpoint I am trying to secure with spring security will never be interacted with via the client.

The login part of the client and api is being handled separate from my api and client I believe it is a form of certificate verification.

What I want to know is there a better way to protect this url and minimize disruption to my front end?

Does spring security have functionality that enables it to work with a separate login service?

Comment: Is your UI is the same spring application? You access URL http://localhost:8080/ for UI and http://localhost:8080/api/... for API call?

Comment: Hi @DhavalGajjar, no my ui is separate angular application localhost:4200 that targets the url of my API

Comment: Check your angular code. It may have code which checks authentication and if you authenticated then show other pages. Spring Security will protecte endpoint of its own. other/3rd party endoint will not be considered.